# Outlook Calendar REST API

Tags: rest, api, calendar, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am trying to create an application to manage and create calendars on Exchange using the Exchange API (Exchange EWS API)

In the documentation, all examples use an endpoint like this

```
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/calendars/{calendar_id}/
```

I have a few questions around this, as I am new to REST:

- I would need to send a request to the target exchange server (which is a local server rather than a public server) to create an entry for a specified user calendar, right?
- What information do I need from the Exchange server admin in order to be able to connect to the right endpoint url?

Comment: I read your post twice, but I still don't understand what exactly you want us to help you with?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I've reworded a bit.. hopefully it make more sense now?

Comment: I cleaned it up a bit more to get to the heart of the problem - is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid yes that was most excellent!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to go through the documentation, as it states clearly [what do you need to get started](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633710(v=exchg.80).aspx#SP15GettingStartedTemplate_WhatDoYouNeed):

> To use the EWS Managed API, you need to have the following:
>
> - A version of the EWS Managed API. The EWS Managed API works with all versions of Exchange starting with Exchange 2007 SP1.
> - A mailbox on an Exchange server that is running a version of Exchange starting with Exchange 2007 SP1, or Office 365 or Exchange
>     Online. You must have the user name and credentials of the account. By
>     default, direct EWS access is enabled for all Exchange Online plans
>     except for the Kiosk plan.
> - A version of the .NET Framework starting with the .NET Framework 3.5.
> - Familiarity with web services and managed programming.

Once you have the above setup, see [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633702(v=exchg.80).aspx) for working specifically with the calendar api; and you may want to look at the [concepts overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dd633649(v=exchg.80).aspx) for some basic background on the API itself.

From your client, you would need the endpoint url for the API, which their Exchange administrator can give you. The endpoint may not be active or may not be accessible from your machine, but all this you can configure with the IT team.